# Read google spreadsheet in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, oauth, google-sheets, gspread

Not very experience with API authentication but I cannot figure out how to read a Google Sheet share with me from Python.

I've tried:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/Users/alexiseggermont/Downloads/Accountable-7b29dac08324.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("mysheet").sheet1
```

This gives me `ImportError: cannot import name 'opentype'` on line 2.

I then tried:

```
import oauth2client.client, oauth2client.file, oauth2client.tools
import gspread

flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds')
storage = oauth2client.file.Storage('credentials.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[oauth2client.tools.argparser]).parse_args([])
    credentials = oauth2client.tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# when this cell is run, your browser will take you to a Google authorization page.
# this authorization is complete, the credentials will be cached in a file named credentials.dat
```

This opens a window asking if I want to give my app access to my sheets, and I click yes. But then `sheet = gc.open("mysheet").sheet1` gives me a permission error:

```
APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

The only suggestion I find to solve this error is to change the 'scope' variable, but there is no scope variable used in that code, so I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add several scopes using spaces. So can you try the following modification?

#### From :

```
flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds')
```

#### To :

```
flow = oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
```

#### Note :

- Before you run the modified script, please remove `credentials.dat`. By this, `credentials.dat` is created using new scopes.
- In my environment, I confirmed that when the scopes is only `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds`, the same error occurs. When the scopes are `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, no error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

there is also Gspread-Pandas library itself, where the docs have a simple intro to the Oauth part, and in a simpler way:
https://github.com/aiguofer/gspread-pandas

> Before using, you will need to download Google client credentials for your app.
>
> Client Credentials To allow a script to use Google Drive API we need
>   to authenticate our self towards Google. To do so, we need to create a
>   project, describing the tool and generate credentials. Please use your
>   web browser and go to Google console and :
>
> Choose Create Project in popup menu on the top. A dialog box appears,
>   so give your project a name and click on Create button. On the
>   left-side menu click on API Manager. A table of available APIs is
>   shown. Switch Drive API and click on Enable API button. Do the same
>   for Sheets API. Other APIs might be switched off, for our purpose. On
>   the left-side menu click on Credentials. In section OAuth consent
>   screen select your email address and give your product a name. Then
>   click on Save button. In section Credentials click on Add credentials
>   and switch OAuth 2.0 client ID. A dialog box Create Cliend ID appears.
>   Select Application type item as Other. Click on Create button. Click
>   on Download JSON icon on the right side of created OAuth 2.0 client
>   IDs and store the downloaded file on your file system. Please be
>   aware, the file contains your private credentials, so take care of the
>   file in the same way you care of your private SSH key; i.e. move
>   downloaded JSON to ~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json (or you
>   can configure the directory and file name by directly calling
>   gspread_pandas.conf.get_config Thanks to similar project df2gspread
>   for this great description of how to get the client credentials.
>
> User Credentials Once you have your client credentials, you can have
>   multiple user credentials stored in the same machine. This can be
>   useful when you have a shared server (for example with a Jupyter
>   notebook server) with multiple people that may want to use the
>   library. The first parameter to Spread must be the key identifying a
>   user's credentials. The first time this is called for a specific key,
>   you will have to authenticate through a text based OAuth prompt; this
>   makes it possible to run on a headless server through ssh or through a
>   Jupyter notebook. After this, the credentials for that user will be
>   stored (by default in ~/.config/gspread_pandas/creds or you can
>   manually set it in GSPREAD_PANDAS_CONFIG_DIR env var) and the tokens
>   will berefreshed automatically any time the tool is used.
>
> Users will only be able to interact with Spreadsheets that they have
>   access to.
>
> Handling Authentication In the backend, the library is leveraging
>   `Google's oauth2client
>   <http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`__ to handle
>   authentication. It conveniently stores everything as described above
>   so that you don't have to worry about boiler plate code to handle
>   auth. However, if you need to customize how you handle authentication
>   you can do so in a few different ways. You can change the directory
>   where everything is stored using the GSPREAD_PANDAS_CONFIG_DIR env
>   var. You can also generate your own
>   oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials and pass them in when
>   instanciating a Client or Spread object. For other ways to customize
>   authentication, see gspread_pandas.conf.get_config and
>   gspread_pandas.conf.get_creds